# How to delete pairs of duplicate across multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as below:

```
dat <- data.frame(
V1=c("A","B","C","A"),
V2=c("B","C","D","B"),
V3=c("C","D","","C"),
V4=c("D","","","E")
)

  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  A  B  C  D
2  B  C  D   
3  C  D      
4  A  B  C  E
```

Row 2 and 3 are in Row 1 in different columns. How can I filter out Row 2 and 3 so that I am left with Row 1 and 4 only?

Comment: This is may need a o(n*n) check ...if speed do matter , check with `Rccp` and write you own function

Answer (score 0):

Paste together each row. Go through the values and check if it (partially) matches any of the values using `grepl`.

```
S = trimws(Reduce(paste, dat), "right")
dat[sapply(1:length(S), function(i) !any(grepl(S[i], S[-i]))),]
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  A  B  C  D
#4  A  B  C  E
```